# Request limit when using async WCF calls?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I'm using async wcf calls inside a loop (say the loops runs for 45 iterations)

```
        ServiceClient client = ServiceClientFactory.Instance().GetServiceClient();

        for (int count = 0; count < 45; count++)
        {

            client.BeginSendCount(textBox1.Text, client_SendCountCompleted , client);

        }
```

when this is happens, not all requests are received at the service (something like 20 only received). But if I do it synchronously all calls are received at the server.

I'm using NetTcp binding with following settings,

closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"

[In here I have tried reducing the timeouts as suggested in some other forums, which didn't do any difference]

Further I'm using a SingleInstance with "NoConcurrency" at the server end (this I have thought thru and it is the best setting for this circumstance ). And hosted in a windows service.

Does anybody have an idea?

Help appreciated.

/BB

Comment: Im sure some of the binding options provide the ability to guarantee ordered and reliable (i.e. acknowledged) delivery....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you using to host the service?  IIS might decide that it's being flooded and stop taking the requests.  i would look into those settings.  alternatively you might find a way to avoid having so many requests.

Comment: this is hosted as a winservice and true i accept the fact that this is too many calls, but this many iterations are a rare occurrence, besides the sync calls work fine. Thanks for the quick reply and I have updated the question with further info.

Comment: You mention you've "reduced timeout times" to help, but i think you ought to extend timeout times, as the server might be under too much load to respond within 1 minute (especially if they are single/no concurrency).  try pushing them all to 10 minutes.

Comment: did you change the timeouts on both the client and server?  "not all requests are received at the service (something like 20 only received). "  which 20?  the first 20 or random 20?